# What does the syntax “(y?)” mean in my woodland mansion coordinates?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

[image]

I’ve tried typing exactly what this says and it simply doesn’t work! I’ve tried several other variations and I just NEED to find out what a woodland mansion looks like myself.

Answer (score 5):

The Y coordinate is undetermined.

Basically, the North/South direction is your X coordinate, and your East/West direction is your Z coordinate. Your Y coordinate is your height.

My guess is that you're searching for a Woodland Mansion since you haven't found one yet, and it's more than likely that those coordinates point to somewhere you haven't been yet. The world generation can determine where on the flat plain (X/Y) to locate objects, but since the world hasn't been generated yet - the hills and valleys, etc, it doesn't know exactly what height it will be at (yet).

You still need a Y coordinate for teleportation, or just `~` to stay on your current height. Alternatively, you can just click the chat output and get the correct teleport command automatically pasted into chat.

Comment: Most features do not have a Y coordinate. Instead, what the game does is pick a XZ point and then try to place it at the most suitable Y coordinate (ie. A ocean monument wouldn't be placed above surface if a single block was to be glitched generated into that one column above water.. For a Woodland Mansion's case, it would be one above the top-most block that is most likely a ground (ie. grass, dirt, stone)

Answer (score 0):

Because the Y coordinate is the elevation/height, you don't need this information in order to find where it is. It's the same reasoning to white you don't write the Y coordinate of your base because it does not matter. You can find it without it.

Comment: What information does this convey that's not already conveyed by Ben's answer?

Comment: I just noticed this was 3 years ago... I'm so sorry for reopening this question...

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with answering old questions on Stack Exchange, but posting answers that duplicate existing answers is pointless.